# Unable to create grid in R

Tags: raster, r

I am new to handling spatial dataset in R. I have been following a tutorial and wanted to create a grid over the raster layer. After running Step 2, I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"
```

Below is the libraries I installed and the code I ran. The raster layer displays properly.

```
library(landscapemetrics)     # landscape metrics calculation
library(sf)                   # spatial vector data reading and handling
library(raster)               # spatial raster data reading and handling
library(dplyr)                # data manipulation


## 1 - READING THE DATA

data("augusta_nlcd")
my_raster = augusta_nlcd

plot(my_raster)

## 2 - CREATING A GRID

my_grid_geom = st_make_grid(my_raster, cellsize = 1500, square = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`st_make_grid` needs an `sf` class object, and not a raster, to get the extent for the grid.

By taking two diagonal corner points of a raster you can make an `sf` object with the same bounds.

For example with a default raster with global bounds:

```
> r = raster()
> extent(r)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -180 
xmax       : 180 
ymin       : -90 
ymax       : 90
```

You can do:

```
> re = st_multipoint(matrix(extent(r),ncol=2))
```

and that is two points in a MULTIPOINT `sf` object:

```
> re
MULTIPOINT ((-180 -90), (180 90))
```

with the same bounds:

```
> st_bbox(re)
xmin ymin xmax ymax 
-180  -90  180   90
```

You can then go on to make a grid based on those two corner points:

```
> st_make_grid(re)
Geometry set for 100 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -180 ymin: -90 xmax: 180 ymax: 90
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 5 geometries:
POLYGON ((-180 -90, -144 -90, -144 -72, -180 -7...
POLYGON ((-144 -90, -108 -90, -108 -72, -144 -7...
POLYGON ((-108 -90, -72 -90, -72 -72, -108 -72,...
POLYGON ((-72 -90, -36 -90, -36 -72, -72 -72, -...
POLYGON ((-36 -90, 0 -90, 0 -72, -36 -72, -36 -...
```

Note that `raster` and `sf` (and `sp` before that) have used different functions for similar operations (`extent` vs `st_bbox` for example). You just have to learn twice as many things...